# Reference of general version of the PBW theorem and its consequences

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, poisson-geometry, pbw-theorems

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with identity and $L$ be a Lie algebra which is also a free module over $A$. I have seen the following statements:

1. The universal enveloping algebra $U(L)$ is isomorphic (as $A$ modules) to the symmetric algebra $S(L)$. (This is stated in the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Birkhoff%E2%80%93Witt_theorem) article of PBW Theorem).
2. The associated graded of the center of $U(L)$ is the Poisson center of $S(L)$.

They are usually stated as the consequence or corollary of the (generalized of) PBW theorem. I would like to have a reference for these results. Mostly the proofs are given in the standard textbook with either $A$ being field of characteristic zero or $L$ being finite-dimensional Lie algebra.

Also, any kind of reference related to the above results will be extremely helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. This is Theorem 5.9 **(a)** in [my diploma thesis](https://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/algebra/pbw.pdf); a few paragraphs down below I give a list of references to proofs. The list is about 10 years out of date now (e.g., [Semmes's notes](https://math.rice.edu/~semmes/tgla.pdf) have the proof too), but there should be enough for anyone there.

Comment: 2. I have never seen this considered part of the PBW theorem (and I wouldn't be surprised if it is not true in this generality). What is the Poisson structure on $S\left(L\right)$? Is it the Lie bracket of $L$ extended to $S\left(L\right)$ as a biderivation (i.e., bilinear map that is a derivation in each argument)?

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thanks for the reference. About 2., you are right. The Poisson structure is the Lie bracket extended to $S(L)$ by Leibniz rule. You may be right about this not being true in general and it has more to do with Duflo isomorphism than PBW. I just want to understand the map between these two centers for the free module $L$.